# How can I bind to a control in the MainWindow from another window in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Basically, my question appears already in the title:
When I have a MainWindow like following:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:easycache"
        xmlns:map="clr-namespace:MapControl;assembly=MapControl.WPF"
        x:Class="easycache.MainWindow"
        x:Name="MainWindow1"
        Title="easycache"
        Height="600"
        Width="850">
  <map:Map Grid.Column="2"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Name="map"
           IsManipulationEnabled="True"
           LightForeground="Black"
           LightBackground="White"
           DarkForeground="White"
           DarkBackground="#FF3F3F3F"
           Center="0.0,0.0"
           ZoomLevel="0.0"
           TileLayer="{Binding Source={StaticResource TileLayersView}, Path=CurrentItem}" />
```

In My Window 2, I have:

```
<map:Map Name="map" IsManipulationEnabled="False"
                 LightForeground="Black" LightBackground="White" DarkForeground="White" DarkBackground="#FF3F3F3F"
                 Center="0.0,0.0" ZoomLevel="{Binding ?????}">
```

And I want to bind the ZoomLevel of the map in Window2 to the ZoomLevel of the map in my MainWindow. How can I achieve this?

Regards,
Ialokim

Comment: If you are doing MVVM it's the ViewModel the ones which should communicate. If you are not is much simpler. Tell me which so I can give a proper answer, regards

Comment: I agree with Hannish - there are a couple different ways this could be done depending on how your program is architected. Are you using MVVM, ViewModels and Bindings anywhere with this? Or is it just straight events and codebehind and whatnot?

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, I'm not using MVVM! So could you please give me an example?

Comment: What's up? @Hannish, please, can you give me an example? I really don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

In your MainWindow codebehind create the a public property with a public get accessor, something like this:

```
private double _mapZoom;
public double MapZoom //I assume that ZoomLevel is of type double, if not use the correct type
{
    get { return _mapZoom; }
    set { _mapZoom = value; OnPropertyChanged("MapZoom"); }
}
```

You'll have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your MainWindow (there is a million examples everywhere, no need to get into that here).

Then, bind your map's ZoomLevel property to the MapZoom property, like this:

```
<map:Map Name="map" ZoomLevel="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=MapZoom}, Mode=TwoWay"/>
```

For this to work, the DataContext of the Window must be the Window itself, in you need one line in the Window's constructor:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this; //add this line
    }
```

You need a way for the second window to call the main window, so you can create a static property to return the current instance in the mainwindow:

```
    private static MainWindow _instance;
    public static MainWindow Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new MainWindow();
            else
                _instance = this;

            return _instance;
        }
    } //you have to make sure to create ONE instance of MainWindow before getting this property, and not to create more instances elsewhere
```

Now you'll have the MainWindow exposing a public property, which is bound to the map's zoom.

So, in your second Window create a property pointing at that instance of the main Window:

```
   public MainWindow Main { get { return MainWindow.Instance; }
```

Finally, you can bind the zoom of the second map to the public property MapZoom which is a member of Main:

```
<map:Map Name="map2" ZoomLevel="{{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Main.MapZoom}, Mode=TwoWay"}">
```

In this binding "Main" is referring to the MainWindow instance through the public property of window2 (set the this.DataContext = this; in window2 too), and accessing the .MapZoom property.

By default, all objects you create in XAML are private, so you have to expose them explicitly with public properties with get/set accessors to make them accesible from outside.

Let me know if this works, I did not create an app to test the code. Regards!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but while waiting for the answer, I tried other attempts to achieve this: I now made a class with the property currentzoom and binded twice to this property.

Comment: This is a WPF anti-pattern and should be avoided: this.DataContext = this;  Instead you should look up how RelativeSource works when applied to a binding.

Comment: @user3690202 you should elaborate more about why a window cannot be its own datacontext, and what you should do is post your own answer showing how to do it your way. Negging is not the way to go here.